# Scroll to other div by scrolling a little bit down/up with mouse wheel

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, single-page-application

This is what I would like to achieve http://www.rogerdubuis.com/ and this is my current code:

```
var offsetArray = Array();
offsetArray[0] = $('header');
offsetArray[1] = $('#puslapis2');
offsetArray[2] = $('#puslapis5');
offsetArray[3] = $('#puslapis7');
offsetArray[4] = $('#puslapis9');
var pos = 0;
var lastScrollTop = 0;

$(window).scroll(function () {
    console.log("pos " + pos);
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (st > lastScrollTop) {
        console.log("Scroll down");
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: offsetArray[pos + 1].ofset().top}, 'slow', function () {pos++;});
    } else {
        console.log("Scroll up");
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: offsetArray[pos - 1].ofset().top}, 'slow', function () {pos--;});
    }
    lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

After scrolling a little bit down, animate should be called only once and pos should increase by one. But it scrolls down and up and mess happends. Any ideas how to prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a plugin to manage single page scrolling like the link you provided. [jQuery Mousewheel Intention](https://github.com/sparksm/jquery-scroll-intention)

Here is a fiddle of what I think you're trying to do. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sparksm/9J9vq/)

```
(function ($) {
    $(function () {
        var scrolling = false;
        var sections = $('.section');
        var container = $('#container');
        var pos = 0;

        function wheelDirection(evt) {
            if (!evt) {
                evt = event;
            }
            return (evt.detail < 0) ? 1 : (evt.wheelDelta > 0) ? 1 : -1;
        }

        function animate(dir) {
            if (scrolling) {
                return;
            }
            var next = $();
            if (dir === 'down') {
                next = sections.eq(pos).next();
            } else {
                next = sections.eq(pos).prev();
            }
            if (!next.length) {
                return;
            }
            scrolling = true;
            container.animate({
                scrollTop: '+=' + next.offset().top
            }, 'slow', function () {
                pos = sections.index(next);
                sections.removeClass('active');
                next.addClass('active');
                scrolling = false;
            });
        }

        function scroll(event) {
            var direction = wheelDirection(event.originalEvent);
            direction = (direction >= 0) ? 'up' : 'down';
            animate(direction);
        }

        function scrollHandler(event) {
            if (event.certainty > 0.6) {
                scroll(event);
            }
        }

        $(window).on('mousewheelintention', scrollHandler);
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 0):

So a few years passed, but for all who are looking for a solution:

Using arrays with jQuery like this doesn't work! (see in your console).

So I decided to make it "personal" so you have to edit it for each new row.

```
wain = 0;
var pos = 0;
var lastpos = 0;
jobdone = false;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    pos = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (pos > lastpos) {
        //Oben?
        if (wain == 0) {
           $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $('#port').offset().top
                }, 'fast');

           wain++;
           lastpos = pos;
       };
   } else if (pos ==lastpos) {
   } else {
       //Portfolio?
       if (wain == 1) {
           $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $('#main').offset().top
                  }, 'fast');
           wain--;
       };                
   };

   lastpos = pos;
```

});

Comment: you just have to c&p the if statement under the comments and replace the WhereAmINumber (wain).Change the #port/#main with the ids you have